# React Native iOS app works fine, but not Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native

React Native iOS app works fine, but Android show white empty screen.

[image]

After run `react-native run-android`, Ctrl+M also not working and this error message in android studio logcat window.

[image]

Comment: Seems like there is some error in your code **(undefined is not a function....)** in the `CarouselPager` screen . You might need to fix that in the first place.

Comment: There is no CarouselPager screen in project, I know there is some error in my code but not sure where to find it.